# Dynamically check if a field in JSON is nil without using eval

Tags: ruby, json, eval

Here's an extract of the code that I am using:

```
def retrieve(user_token, quote_id, check="quotes")
  end_time = Time.now + 15
  match = false
  until Time.now > end_time || match
    @response = http_request.get(quote_get_url(quote_id, user_token))
    eval("match = !JSON.parse(@response.body)#{field(check)}.nil?")
  end
  match.eql?(false) ? nil : @response
end

private

def field (check)
  hash = {"quotes" => '["quotes"][0]',
 "transaction-items" => '["quotes"][0]["links"]["transactionItems"]'
  }
  hash[check]
end
```

I was informed that using `eval` in this manner is not good practice. Could anyone suggest a better way of dynamically checking the existence of a JSON node (field?). I want this to do:

```
psudo: match = !JSON.parse(@response.body) + dynamic-path + .nil?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store paths as arrays of path elements (`['quotes', 0]`). With a little helper function you'll be able to avoid eval. It is, indeed, completely inappropriate here.

Something along these lines:

```
class Hash
  def deep_get(path)
    path.reduce(self) do |memo, path_element|
      return unless memo
      memo[path_element]
    end
  end
end

path = ['quotes', 0]
hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
match = !hash.deep_get(path).nil?
```